# Como saber se minhas threads estão mesmo executando ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

A dúvida surgiu em um trabalho da faculdade onde precisamos fazer o uso de threads em [c](/questions/tagged/c). Foi pedido que estudássemos sobre a *"libpthread"* para conseguirmos seguir adiante com o trabalho. O material que estou encontrando em minhas pesquisas não sanam minhas dúvidas e a documentação oficial achei um tanto confusa. Considerem o código a seguir:

```
/*
    Nesse código bobo, 4 threads são encarregadas de printar sua parte correspondente do vetor, é 
    um vetor de 20 elementos e cada thread está responsável por 5 deles
*/
#include 
#include 
#include 
#include 

typedef struct _lista_numeros {
    int *ponteiro_Lista;
    int parametro;
} lista_numeros;

void imprime_lista (lista_numeros *lista, int inicio, int fim)
{
    int i;
    for (i=inicio; iponteiro_Lista[i]);
    
    printf("\n");
}

void * rotina_de_impressao (void *parametro)
{
    //Pegando o parametro void que chegou e convertendo para t_lista
    lista_numeros *nova_lista = (lista_numeros *) parametro;

    switch (nova_lista->parametro)
    {
        case 1: printf("Thread 1 executando...\n"); imprime_lista(nova_lista, 0, 5); break;
        case 2: sleep(20); printf("Thread 2 executando...\n"); imprime_lista(nova_lista, 5, 10); break;
        case 3: printf("Thread 3 executando...\n"); imprime_lista(nova_lista, 10, 15); break;
        case 4: printf("Thread 4 executando...\n"); imprime_lista(nova_lista, 15, 20); break;
        default: printf("Nenhuma thread em trabalho!"); break;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    //As tais 4 threads responsáveis pela impressão
    pthread_t tarefas[4];
    
    lista_numeros primeira_lista;

    int lista[20] = {/*Para a thread 1*/60,57,8,77,32, /*Para a thread 2*/98,71,95,2,33, 
                    
                    /*Para a thread 3*/24,68,14,85,36, /*Para a thread 4*/25,88,76,11,34};

    primeira_lista.ponteiro_Lista = lista;
    
    primeira_lista.parametro = 1;
    pthread_create(&tarefas[0], NULL, rotina_de_impressao, (void *) &primeira_lista);
    pthread_join(tarefas[0], NULL);

    primeira_lista.parametro = 2;
    pthread_create(&tarefas[1], NULL, rotina_de_impressao, (void *) &primeira_lista);
    pthread_join(tarefas[1], NULL);

    primeira_lista.parametro = 3;
    pthread_create(&tarefas[2], NULL, rotina_de_impressao, (void *) &primeira_lista);
    pthread_join(tarefas[2], NULL);

    primeira_lista.parametro = 4;
    pthread_create(&tarefas[3], NULL, rotina_de_impressao, (void *) &primeira_lista);
    pthread_join(tarefas[3], NULL);
   
    return 0;
}
```

Notem que na função *"rotina_de_impressao"*, caso o valor do parâmetro seja 2, eu coloco um **sleep** de 20 para atrasar a thread 2, apenas para verificar se as threads 3 e 4 seriam executadas, pois é o que eu esperava, já que a ideia das threads é executar trechos de código ao mesmo tempo né, mas o que aconteceu é que a saída foi a mesma de não ter o sleep ali, ele primeiro esperou o sleep e só depois executou as threads 3 e 4. Não usei loop for na criação das threads apenas para didática. Tentei tirar o pthread_join para ver se as threads executavam de fato ao mesmo tempo, mas o que aconteceu foi um fluxo de execução completamente irregular.

Saída com `sleep()` e sem `sleep()` foi a mesma, segue abaixo:

```
Thread 1 executando...
[60] [57] [8] [77] [32]
Thread 2 executando...
[98] [71] [95] [2] [33]
Thread 3 executando...
[24] [68] [14] [85] [36]
Thread 4 executando...
[25] [88] [76] [11] [34]
```

Como faço para de fato executar dois trechos de código ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Não use cumprimentos ou saudações nas perguntas, veja [que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Answer (score 0):

O problema do seu código é que você está iniciando uma *thread* e em seguida *join*ando ela. Você tem quatro bumerangues e quer lançá-los ao mesmo tempo. Você 1) joga o primeiro bumerangue, espera ele voltar e se posiciona para segurá-lo; joga o segundo, espera ele voltar e se posiciona para segurá-lo; ...; ou 2) joga os quatro bumeranges ao mesmo tempo e se posiciona para segurá-los conforme eles vão chegando?

Nessa analogia, a *thread* é o bumerangue, lançá-lo é o `pthread_create` e se posicionar para segurá-lo é o `pthread_join`. Dito isso, você pode refatorar o seu código para

```c
primeira_lista.parametro = 1;
pthread_create(&tarefas[0], NULL, rotina_de_impressao, (void *) &primeira_lista);

primeira_lista.parametro = 2;
pthread_create(&tarefas[1], NULL, rotina_de_impressao, (void *) &primeira_lista);

primeira_lista.parametro = 3;
pthread_create(&tarefas[2], NULL, rotina_de_impressao, (void *) &primeira_lista);

primeira_lista.parametro = 4;
pthread_create(&tarefas[3], NULL, rotina_de_impressao, (void *) &primeira_lista);

pthread_join(tarefas[0], NULL);
pthread_join(tarefas[1], NULL);
pthread_join(tarefas[2], NULL);
pthread_join(tarefas[3], NULL);
```

---

No entanto, ainda haverão inconsistências no seu código visto que a variável `primeira_lista` está sendo usada pelas quatro *threads* ao mesmo tempo, podendo haver problemas de sincronização. Existem formas de contornar isso, mas a mais *ad hoc* é você criar cinco arrays para cada *thread*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void imprime_lista (int numeros[5])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%d ", numeros[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void * rotina_de_impressao (void *parametro)
{
    int *nova_lista = (int *) parametro;

    int n = nova_lista[0];
    if (n == 2) sleep(5);

    printf("Thread %d executando...\n", n);
    imprime_lista(nova_lista + 1);
}

int main ()
{
    pthread_t tarefas[4];
    
    int p1[6] = {1, 60, 57, 8, 77, 32};
    int p2[6] = {2, 98, 71, 95, 2, 33};
    int p3[6] = {3, 24, 68, 14, 85, 36};
    int p4[6] = {4, 25, 88, 76, 11, 34};

    pthread_create(&tarefas[0], NULL, rotina_de_impressao, (void *) &p1);
    pthread_create(&tarefas[1], NULL, rotina_de_impressao, (void *) &p2);
    pthread_create(&tarefas[2], NULL, rotina_de_impressao, (void *) &p3);
    pthread_create(&tarefas[3], NULL, rotina_de_impressao, (void *) &p4);

    pthread_join(tarefas[0], NULL);
    pthread_join(tarefas[1], NULL);
    pthread_join(tarefas[2], NULL);
    pthread_join(tarefas[3], NULL);
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, Enzo! O trabalho que estou fazendo possuí uma fila de prioridade, onde eu preciso tratar os 5 primeiros elementos ao mesmo tempo, por isso o uso das threads. Só que nesse caso é apenas uma fila, a ideia era que todas as threads trabalhassem na mesma lista, nesse caso então, eu meio que deveria criar outras rotinas de impressão para evitar problemas de sincronia? Fiz esse para este problema bobo e deu certo, mas o código fica muito poluído com uma rotina para cada thread :|